# Query to fetch total in Table

Tags: mysql, sqlite

My table:

```
invoice_id    |    order_id    |    unit_price    |    number_units
  1                  1                5                   10
  1                  2                5                   10
```

What will be SQLite or MySQL query to get total amount of invoice_id = 1 i.e 50 + 50 = 100 ?

Comment: You mean COUNT()?

Comment: do you want to total of all number_units multiplied by unit_price ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this mysql query

```
select sum(unit_price*number_units) as total from table_name where invoice_id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Tushar, actually I'm getting an error "Raw query must include the primary key" when executing it in Django.